# Bittrex API, generating a wallet address for XRP returns a tag but no address

Tags: api, ripple, bittrex

So I'm trying to generate an address to send XRP to Bittrex via their API. They return the JSON as such:

`{"Currency"=>"XRP", "Address"=>"2705xxxxx"}`

Do I just use the tag given and assume the actual XRP address will always be the same?

Am I not allowed to make multiple "destination" addresses? Say I want to send 100XRP from A->B (on Bittrex) and then another amount say 250XRP from C->D (on Bittrex).

Thank you!

Comment: The deposit address is static, you can contact their support if you want a new one.

Comment: What do you mean by "the tag given" - given where, could you please elaborate? Binance returns addressTag directly in the JSON response. Bittrex makes it confusing.

Answer (score 1):

No you're not allowed to have multiple addresses on Bittrex and by so a generated addresse will always be the same. You can confirm it

Comment: Does any other exchange allow to have multiple addresses?